# if else condition in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to write a sql query that does:

`if` this query `(select X from table1 where x = 'value1')` has result return 1 `else if (select x from table2 where x = 'value2')` has any result return 2 else return 0.

Thanks

Comment: Post your question regarding the reading of data sets in C# as a separate question.  Or, more appropriately, search for the numerous existing answers and websites that cover that already.

Comment: @Yuck ok, I will edit my question, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method is a `select` and `case`:

```
select (case when exists (select X from table1 where x = 'value1')
             then 1
             when exists (select x from table2 where x = 'value2')
             then 2
             else 0
        end) as flag
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I read the 'Then' part from c#? how can I access it?

Comment: Suppose you wanted to execute the query `select 1;` from C#. Do you know how to do that? If you do, then you also know how to run Gordon's query from C#. The fact that it uses `case` is irrelevant; they're both just queries that return a single integer. If you don't, then you should look up a tutorial on database access in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to implement with variables:

```
DECLARE @FLAG INT = 0;

SELECT @FLAG = 1 FROM table1 WHERE x = 'value1'

IF @FLAG = 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT @FLAG = 2 FROM table2 WHERE x = 'value2'
END

SELECT @FLAG
```

The `@FLAG` variable will hold the value 0, 1 or 2 as the tables contains or not data. If the 1st select does not contain data, then you run the second, if none return data, then return 0 (default `@FLAG` value).

Answer (score 0):

This should work although it's not an efficient query nor a best practice to use queries like that.

```
select 
    case when exists (select X from table1 where x = 'value1') then 1 
    when exists (select x from table2 where x = 'value2') then 2 
    else 0 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select case is better way to solve this situation when query is short. But when query is long and complex i like to use user defined functions like:

IF dbo.QueryExecution() IS NULL
   --do something
ELSE
   --do something

And dbo.QueryExecution() can execute your query 
select X from table1 where x = 'value1'.

On this way it is easier to test and maintain query (at least it is easier to me).